# Specify foreign key reference in Spring Data Rest, Update Request using HTTP PUT

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Indications")
@NamedQuery(name="Indication.findAll", query="SELECT i FROM Indication i")
public class Indication implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IndicationID")
    private int indicationID;

    @Column(name="IndicationDescription")
    private String indicationDescription;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ParentIndicationID")
    private Indication indication;

}
```

As is evident in the entity the table has 3 columns

- IndicationID which is a primary key
- IndicationDescription which is a string
- Indication which is a foreign key reference to a row in the same table, so it is many-to-one relationship

Since I am using Spring Data Rest I can create a new record using HTTP POST with the following body

```
{
    "indicationDescription": "dummy1",
    "indication": "/indications/1"
}
```

This creates a new row in the database with the content dummy1 and creates a foreign key reference to the record with id 1.

But when I try to update the foreign key reference using HTTP PUT with the following body

```
{
    "indicationDescription": "dummy2",
    "indication": "/indications/2"
}
```

While it updates the indicationDescription it does not actually update the foreign key reference.

I am aware that I can update the foreign key reference by using the URL http://localhost:8080/indications/7733/indication
and sending body as
http://localhost:8080/indications/2
after setting the content type to text/uri-list

My question is , Is there a way to perform the update in one request using the body similar to the one I used for creation of the record instead of making another update request using the URL - http://localhost:8080/indications/7733/indication

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to update a foreign key you would need two ids: one of the indication to be updated, and one is the new value to replace the old one. Please show your current update code.

Comment: I am sending the second body mentioned above with dummy2 to URL - http://localhost:8080/indications/7733 using HTTP PUT, so from what I understand both the ids are being mentioned, the id of the record to update is in the URL, the id of the foreign key is in the body, and it is not updating the foreign key reference but only the field indicationDescription which is a string field. Do I need to do something different, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can confirm that I have tried adding the id in the request body as suggested by @JAsgarov in addition to already having it mentioned in the request URL but that did not fix the problem, the foreign key reference is still not being updated while the indicationDescription field gets updated as expected. And so the body -> { "indicationID:7733
    "indicationDescription": "dummy2",
    "indication": "/indications/2"
} sent to URL localhost:8080/indications/7733 as a PUT operation is updating indicationDescription to "dummy2" but the foreign key indication is still pointing to 1 instead of 2.